# Iodine in Windows error

Tags: windows, ssh, dns, tap, tunneling

I am trying to run iodine in Windows but I am getting this error and I have no idea why. I tried running it as Administrator but does not work too.

```
C:\>iodine.exe -f -P test 'redacted IP' blah.domain.com
Error opening registry key ░≤"
No TAP adapters found. Version 0801 and 0901 are supported.
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't have the tap adapter installed. You can install it using openvpn windows installer: https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/

You can install it selection only the tap adapter from the options while installing.